# Custom start-up command for Azure Node.js Web app (ES2015/babel)?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am migrating an ES2015 node.js application from Heroku to Azure.

The current start-up command running on Heroku is

```
"start": "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js index.js"
```

However, on Azure I am getting

> Invalid start-up command "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js index.js" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".

Which indicates that Azure only supports vanilla node for `npm start`.

I'm aware that running babel-node on production isn't ideal, but I was hoping for a straightforward migration.

Three options that would require a bit of re-architecting are:

1. Using a gulp workflow to precompile ES2015: https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-node-es2015-example
2. Using a bash workflow to precompile ES2015: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/dbaskin/deploying-an-es6-jspm-nodejs-application-to-azure
3. Using `babel-register` ala [link in comments].

I suspect option 3 will be easiest but checking if anyone has come across a similar issue and managed to run `babel-node` directly in `npm start` on Azure.

Comment: babel-register reference: https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/08/running-babeljses2015-apps-in-azure-app-service/

Answer (score 9):

According your issue, please modify your `start` npm script to `node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js index.js` on Azure Web Apps.

Here is the content in test `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "description": "A basic website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.9.1",
    "npm": "3.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Meanwhile if you need a higher Node.js version, you can specify in `package.json`, refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/ for more.

Comment: Thanks @gary-liu-msft. That makes total sense (d'oh!) however: `Start script "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js index.js" from package.json is not found.`. I'm assuming Azure deployment scripts are checked before an `npm install` is run to include the dependencies?

Comment: Did you get the error message after you modifying the script? And I will update my `packege.json` file in my test project for your information.

Comment: Yes. There is a chicken-and-egg situation here. Azure deployment can't find the `node_modules` dir because it hasn't run `npm install` to install dependencies. I've read some people are storing and deploying `node_modules` which is horrible, but in my case trying just for the `babel-cli` module returns `Failed to stat file 'D:/home/site/repository/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/bin-version-check/node_modules/bin-version/node_modules/find-versions/node_modules/........../node_modules/builtin-modules/builtin-modules.json': The data area passed to a system call is too small.`

Comment: It seems the path is too long and exceed the system limitation. You can try to use higher node.js and npm version. Set the "engines" as it's shown in my `package.json` content.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Bumping the node version up won't (didn't) help. I think it's safe to say the Azure platform isn't going to work for this application and its dependencies.

Comment: Could you post your detailed error message for diagnosis? It could be something wrong with your configuration, because it works fine on my side.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT Sorry to hijack this question but I'm having the same issue ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723818/custom-startup-command-for-node-js-app-on-azure-with-babel-6?noredirect=1#comment66745346_39723818)). Any chance you could take a look?

Answer (score 4):

Just as what Gary said, you need to update your `package.json` using the command below.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js index.js"
  }
```