# Custom startup command for Node.js app on Azure with Babel 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm having the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704917/custom-start-up-command-for-azure-node-js-web-app-es2015-babel) which wasn't really resolved as the original questioner abandoned this route. I'm trying to run a node app on Azure using Babel6. The `package.json` file I'm using has the following in it:

```
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node ./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js"
   }
```

I've checked using the Azure console and the `babel-cli` node module is installed and the `server.js` file is in `wwwroot`. Despite this I get the following when I commit to Azure:

```
remote: Start script "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js
        server.js" from package.json is not found.
```

The npm version running on Azure is 3.10.3, node version is 6.6.0. Can anyone advise on how to get this up and running. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: what is your file name where you starting node app? I mean how to run node app on local PC?

Comment: The file that starts the node app is called `server.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that to run node.js applications in ES2015 on Web Apps. We need to compile them to ES5 version, you can leverage [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to achieve this.

Here is [example](https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-node-es2015-example) repos on GitHub, which leverages `gulp` and custom deployment script to compile the node.js from ES6 to ES5 via the Azure deployment task.

Specially, this example defines several scripts in `package.json` for the deployment task calling:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "gulp nodemon",
    "build": "gulp build"
  },
```

And manually call the npm scripts in `deploy.cmd` before `KuduSync` task move the deployment folder to production folder.

```
:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 0. Select node version for build
call :SelectNodeVersion

:: 1. Install build dependencies
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd

:: 2. Run build command
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run-script build
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd
```

Comment: Many thanks Gary, appreciate you looking at this. I actually worked something similar out last night and got it working but your solution is more elegant so I'll use your method instead!