# Deploying Aurelia application to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, aurelia

I have followed all the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) to deploy my Aurelia application to Azure, however I am getting the following error when I try to access the application URL:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

My application is essentially the same as the skeleton app and has no `server.js` or `node.js` file.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to deploy my application?

Answer (score 0):

According the intrdocution:

> Aurelia is a next generation UI framework.

Which means that the Aurelia is a fronted javascript library, and a Node.js server application, which should be based on a HTML+CSS application architecture. **Need a index.html file in the root directory of your application at least.** You can make a complete Aurelia application as mentioned at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1, and deploy it to Azure.

Furthermore, we can leverage [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to bundle the Javascript sources via gulp or babel, you can refer the answer of [Custom startup command for Node.js app on Azure with Babel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723818/custom-startup-command-for-node-js-app-on-azure-with-babel-6/39737685#39737685) for details.

Comment: I have an index.html and a working aurelia application. I'm using the deploy script found [here](http://www.webnotwar.ca/opensource/azure-web-app-continuous-integration-with-aurelia-and-github/) but still no joy

Comment: Could you use KUDU or App Service Editor on your Azure Portal App Service blade, to check whether there is a `web.config` in your root directory, and if you don't contain a `server.js` or `app.js` in the root directory, you can try to delete `web.config`.