# Azure Web App unexpected "Bad Request"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm occasionally getting "Bad Request" in the Azure Console (located in the main 'blade' of the Azure web app). One example is when running `npm install grunt-sass` but there were several other times with different commands, all of which are valid commands that should execute immediately with no errors.

[image]

[image]

I think this is a bug in Azure. I haven't seen the problem when using the Kudu Diagnostic Console.

Why is this happening?

Comment: When you say `Azure Console`, do you mean the Console under **App Service Editor (Preview)**?

Comment: No, I clarified in the post. I just learned about the App Service Editor and will start using it. I've been using the Kudu console and the one mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, it looks like depends on the npm version in the Azure Web Apps sanbox. I upgrade the npm version to `4.2.0`, and successfully installed `grunt-sass` both via Kudu Conosole, or App Service Editor's Console Tool.

Please navigate to **Application settings** blade of your Azure Web Apps, and add the `WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION` configuration in **App settings** section:
[image]

Then, it should work as expected.

In Kudu Console:
[image]

In App Service Editor:[image]

At last, we recommend you can leverage custom deployment of Azure Web Apps, you can configure your dependencies in `package.json`, and deploy to Azure via Git, the deployment task will install the dependencies automatically, you can refer to [Custom startup command for Node.js app on Azure with Babel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723818/custom-startup-command-for-node-js-app-on-azure-with-babel-6/39737685#39737685) for the similar steps.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you're having a `"Bad Request"` error while running the `npm install` command in Azure App Service's Console, the `npm` process is still running in the background and it will complete.

That means that you should not try to run `npm i` again until it completes. You can monitor the progress via FTP - when the `.staging` folder in `node_modules` is empty, that means installation is complete.