# deploying es2015 nodejs site to azure

Tags: node.js, azure, ecmascript-6

I am building a site with node.js express
and this is my file structure:
[local file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnB32.png)

the dist folder holds the packed version of the site and the src the dev
also I have 2 server file once for each version.
I went with that style after doing a pluralsight course with the same style.

my npm start script is:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js tools/distServer.
},
```

locally it works great.
I hooked my azure webapp to my github repo for this project and each time it tells me the the build was successfully even that at first it looked for a server.js file at the root, I added it later as a copy of the distServer file.
and then I noticed another error:

```
"Start script "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js" from package.json is not found."
```

as the built was successful I didn't pay too much attention to it, but when I try to access the site it returns only 500 errors
once I checked the logs they were full of:

```
import express from 'express';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I have no idea how to make it work on azure, like it does locally and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom startup command for Node.js app on Azure with Babel 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723818/custom-startup-command-for-node-js-app-on-azure-with-babel-6)

Comment: thanks I'll check it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your local node js version does not match you node js version on azure .

Compare your node js version by doing (node -v or nodejs -v ) on both environnement .

Comment: I have checked that but they are of the same version.
I have decided eventually to go back to use require as it wasn't a must to use import statements